# A particle moves along a circle of radius $\frac{20}{\pi}$ with constant tangential acceleration.

Tags: physics, kinematics

> If the speed of the particle is $80\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}$ at the end of second revolution. Find the tangential acceleration (object starts from rest)

$V=R\omega$

$\omega =4\pi$ rad/s

Now 
$$\omega^2=2\alpha\theta$$
$$16\pi^2=8\pi\alpha$$
$$\alpha=2\pi $$

Then 
$$a=R\alpha$$
$$a=40m/s^2$$

But the answer is $80.$ What’s going wrong?

*To be clear, I have a perfectly valid solution with me that is convincing enough to get 80m/s^2. I just want to know what’s wrong with this*

Upon request, here is the solution [image]

Comment: $\theta = 4\pi$, not $\omega$

Comment: $\omega=4\pi$, obtained from $V=R\omega$ @LucasHenrique

Comment: It can't be. $4\pi$ is an angle measure, not angular velocity. And you don't have $R$.

Comment: @LucasHenrique OP definitely meant $4 \pi\, \text{rad/s}$, and also in his posted work, the $\alpha$ was missing units, but I'm pretty sure the numerical calculations are right, and that the tangential acceleration does indeed have a magnitude of $40 \text{m/s}^2$ (unless I also made a mistake). (both $\omega$ and $\theta$ at the end of two cycles have magnitude $4 \pi$)

Comment: $R=\frac{20}{\pi}$ it’s given in the question @LucasHenrique

Comment: @peek-a-boo please check the note I added

Comment: at the moment I can't see anything wrong with this, but don't take this as gospel (I'm usually very bad with simple computational problems like this, because I make all sorts of errors), but please, by all means post your proposed solution.

Comment: @peek-a-boo done

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry lol. I don't know how I missed the title.

Comment: are you sure it makes two revolutions? because if you plug in only one revolution, then $\theta = 2 \pi$ and $\omega = 4 \pi$, which yields $\alpha = 4 \pi$ and hence $|\vec{a}_{tan}| = 80$

Comment: @peek-a-boo the question did say it’s 2 revolutions, but I see the problem here. The solution is very clearly wrong, and we can conclude that 40 is the correct answer. Right?

Comment: the (printed) solution is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer of $a = 40$ m/s$^2$ is correct. Assuming $2$ revolutions, the proposed solution has an arithmetic mistake. The first line is correct, but the second line is wrong. It should be
\begin{align}
a &= \dfrac{v^2}{2d} = \dfrac{v^2}{2 (2 \cdot (2 \pi R))} = 40
\end{align}
First equality is by rearranging $v = \sqrt{2ad}$. The second is by substituting $d = 2(2 \pi R)$, which is the distance travelled at the end of two revolutions and the third is by substituting $v=80$ at the end of two cycles, $R= 20/\pi$.

So, the mistake is that the solution is missing an extra factor of $2$ in the denominator.

---

(of course, insert units everywhere to be formally correct)

Answer (score 2):

Your solution seems correct, and the book's solution is wrong. First of all, $d = R\theta = 4\pi R.$ Look at the first 2 equalities after the "$\therefore$":

> $a = \frac{v^2}{ad} = \frac{v^2}{2(2\pi R)}$

The first equality has a typo; it should be $\frac{v^2 }{2d}$. Assuming this, $\frac{v^2}{2d} =  \frac{v^2}{2(2\pi R)}$ so $d =  2\pi R \neq 4\pi R, \quad\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow.$